# How to generate a stream using an index rather than the previous element?

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I generate a stream of "new" data? Specifically, I want to be able to create data that includes functions that are not reversible. 
If I want to create a stream [from an Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-)
I do

```
Stream.of(arr)
```

[From a collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--)

```
col.stream()
```

A [constant stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) can be made with a lambda expression

```
Stream.generate(() -> "constant")
```

A [stream based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) on the last input (any reversible function) may be achieved by

```
Stream.iterate(0, x -> x + 2)
```

But if I want to create a more general generator (say output of whether a number is divisive by three: 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1...) without creating a new class.

The main issue is that I need to have some way of inputing the index into the lambda, because I want to have a pattern, and not to be dependent on the last output of the function.

Note:
`someStream.limit(length)` may use to stop the length of the stream, so infinite stream generator is actually what I am looking for.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have an infinite stream for a function taking an index, you may consider creating a “*practically infinite*” stream using

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).map(index -> your lambda)
```

resp.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).mapToObj(index -> your lambda)
```

for a `Stream` rather than an `IntStream`.

This isn’t truly infinite, but there are no `int` values to represent indices after `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so you have a *semantic* problem to solve when ever hitting that index.

Also, when using `LongStream.rangeClosed(0, Long.MAX_VALUE).map(index -> yourLambda)` instead and each element evaluation takes only a nanosecond, it will take almost three hundred years to process all elements.

But, of course, there is a way to create a truly infinite stream using

```
Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE::add).map(index -> yourLambda)
```

which might run forever, or more likely, bail out with an `OutOfMemoryError` once the index can’t be presented in the heap memory anymore, if your processing ever gets that far.

Note that streams constructed using `range[Closed]` might be more effcient than streams constructed using `Stream.iterate`.

Comment: Note on the note, iterate is less efficient and more general. It exists for int and long, so when streaming something other than that (or when streaming not in consecutive order) iterate should be used, as in the last example.

Comment: @borgr: even the last example could be written as `LongStream.range(0, Long.MAX_VALUE) .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)`, if you can live with the fact that it is not theoretically infinite anymore. For practical purposes, this is preferable and applicable to all tasks where the stream element can be calculated from an index. `iterate` is useful for exactly the use case your question is *not* about, when the calculation of an element needs the previous element (in a nontrivial way).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    Stream<Integer> s = Stream.generate(() -> counter.getAndIncrement());
```

Comment: You can even do `Stream.generate(counter::getAndIncrement);` to make it shorter

Comment: but you do create an instance for that, and you can only increase with that not do anything generic

Comment: @Ferrybig Yes, but I didn't want to frustrate topic starter with advanced syntax. He may be not familiar with it yet,

Comment: You can actually skip the variable if you go with a method reference: `Stream.generate(new AtomicInteger()::getAndIncrement);`

Comment: @shmosel nice, but I think readability may suffer in this case. It isn't clear from first sight that `new AtomicInteger()` is invoked only once.

Comment: This stream is infinite, but looping in a way that is not intended in most cases. You may use `IntStream.rangeClosed(0,Integer.MAX_VALUE).boxed()` instead and *if* you ever encounter the difference between them, it is time to rethink what you *actually* want to do with an “infinite” stream that produces ascending `Integer`s (though, `Stream.generate(…)` formally produces an *unordered* stream, even if the generator returns ascending numbers)…

Comment: @talex It is clear to me. I guess it depends on how comfortable you are with lambdas and method references.